# clone ssocr source code and build in my GCP Ubuntu but failed after make command

Tags: git

I ran the code below

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
sudo apt-get install libimlib2-dev
```

and paste "make" in my ubuntu on GCP but requested to install make package so I use the command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

and after that I use `make` command in ssocr dir and an error message below:

```
make: imlib2-config: Command not found   
make: imlib2-config: Command not found   
cc -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wall -W -Wextra -pedantic -Werror -pedantic-errors -fstack-protector-all -O3 -c -o ssocr.o ssocr.c   
ssocr.c:21:53: fatal error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory   
compilation terminated.   
<builtin>: recipe for target 'ssocr.o' failed   
make: *** [ssocr.o] Error 1
```

So please comment how to fix it.

Comment: Did the first `sudo apt-get install` command complete without errors? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: It looked so and only informed me some memory space will be added and asked me [Y/n]. But one thing I did noted was once Y input it showed "Abort". My ubuntu was 16.04.3. Should I run 'sudo apt-get install' again? @N0bert

Comment: I run `sudo apt-get install libimlib2-dev` again and it works now.